# using ngfor with observables that is dynamic inside another ngfor

Tags: angular

the problem is that I want to call a rest api to get data and fill it by ngFor
but my rest api gets a value and that value comes from another ngfor in a higher level. after running the program the nested ngfor goes to infinite loop which i believe is because of change detector.

I have tried many options for example i totally deactivated change detector 
but it was not useful I also understood  my problem is that my rest api gets a value and is dependent on another ngfor so i cannot put it in my typescript file

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let item of requirementElementsList;">
    <input *ngIf="item.elementType == 1">
    <select *ngIf="item.elementType == 2">
        <option class="option"
                *ngFor="let elementOption of getElementOptions(item.elementId) | async">
            {{elementOption.title}}
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello Sadra, in this scenarios I think is really important to see the whole picture, so that people can reproduce.. and the html doesn't help much to figure out what is going behind the scenes.. on the component for example.. you can use something like https://stackblitz.com to create a working snippet and ask for someone to review..

Comment: tnx for your comment yes i know that but the problem is how can i create rest api in stackblitz. how can i have a virtual database that i can send and get data from it my actual database is in a local network and there is no access to it

Comment: Hi, one suggestion from my side, you can try using angular reactive form. but it is not related to your problem. To understand why you are facing a infinite loop, one reads to get your code. try to create a stackblitz as mjoia says.
and it think you can get all the data initially and later just map it to get the options.

Comment: @sadraseyfi you can mock the data.. add a timeout to have a delay but I see your point